# How to split array of objects into separate variables in an Array

Tags: powershell

How do i split array of objects into separate variables in powershell .

query

$d2 = aws --profile $profile ce get-cost-and-usage-with-resources --time-period Start=$start,End=$end --filter = "SERVICE = AmazonCloudWatch" --granularity=MONTHLY  --metrics UnblendedCost  | convertfrom-json

$d2.resultsbytime.groups

Keys                                 Metrics

{AmazonCloudWatch, USW2-CW:Requests} @{BlendedCost=; UnblendedCost=; UsageQuantity=}

$d2.resultsbytime.groups| ? {$_.keys -match "AmazonCloudWatch"}

Keys

{AmazonCloudWatch, APN1-CW:GMD-Metrics}

**it should look like below in the output**

Key = AmazonCloudWatch

Value  = APN1-CW:GMD-Metrics

Comment: please, write quetions we can answer. When asking for algorithms, you should write example input data, example output data and a detailed description on how does the transformation needs to happen.

Comment: fixed the formatting. sorry

Comment: Just as an advice. If you write a code that anybody can tyr, I am pretty sure you will get the answer. Now you need to find somebody with free time and aws account to try it out. For example, you can use the code formating tags, and write a test case in this link, and ask people to complete it: https://code.labstack.com/PcnFq3dx